# what is ChaseNS in this pointer-chasing benchmark

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, benchmarking

Trying to figure the output of following benchmark from google:

https://github.com/google/multichase

and output is like:

```
   ./multiload -s 16 -n 5 -t 16 -m 512M -c chaseload -l stream-sum
    Samples , Byte/thd  , ChaseThds , ChaseNS   , ChaseMibs , ChDeviate , LoadThds  , LdMaxMibs , LdAvgMibs , LdDeviate , ChaseArg  , MemLdArg
    5       , 536870912     , 1         , 212.726   , 36        , 0.017     , 15        , 17427     , 17331     , 0.012     , chaseload , stream-sum
```

What is ChaseNS here, is it the time taken to access every 16th byte from an array of 512MB ?

and

ChaseMibs is bandwidth we get while accessing the addresses at this 16th byte ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume it's nanoseconds per something.  Perhaps per load (dereference).  212 ns is a *long* time to wait for a cache-miss load, but with contention from multiple cores it's maybe plausible?

> is it the time taken to access every 16th byte from an array of 512MB?

This is a [pointer-chasing](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/pointer_chasing#:%7E:text=Pointer%20chasing%20refers%20to%20a,serially%2Ddependent%20chain%20of%20loads.) microbenchmark, like `p = p->next`, so you're measuring load latency by making each load-address dependent on the previous load's result.  So hopefully the access pattern is *not* regular, otherwise hardware prefetching would defeat it, by having the next thing to load already in local L1d cache before the load-address is known.

e.g. make an array of pointers to pointers (like `struct foo { struct foo *next; };`) with each one pointing to the next, then shuffle it, so iterating over that linked list touches cache lines in a random order within that 512 MiB working set.

---

I guess ChaseThds = 1 / LoadThds = 15 saying that we have 1 thread chasing pointers, and 15 other threads trying to saturate memory bandwidth?  That would do it.  They're not waiting for a load to complete before starting the next one, so each of those load threads can achieve some memory-level parallelism (doing memset or memcpy, or memchr or whatever), and we can see they're achieving 17331 MiB/s.

Oh, "stream-sum" is probably A[i] = B[i] + C[i], like the Dr. Bandwidth's [STREAM benchmark](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/), perhaps exactly that code.

(I doubt they really mean Mib mibi-*bits*.  It's weird to be precise about using SI binary-prefix Mi, but then use b (bits) instead of B bytes.  But 17 GiB/s is a typical memory-bandwidth number for a modern-ish system.)

I don't know exactly what this benchmark does to construct its data, and if the load threads are reading their own block of memory or the same array of pointers.  I didn't look at the github page for it, the name alone and the results make the basics pretty clear, that's it's a memory latency benchmark done the usual way.

---

Dr. Bandwidth [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620752/what-is-chasens-in-this-pointer-chasing-benchmark/72624706?noredirect=1#comment128356478_72624706) that **this benchmark uses a geometric mean to calculate the `ChaseNS`.  This is usually not what you want for  average latency.**  Min/max / arithmetic mean +- standard deviation is typically more meaningful.  And stuff like looking at 90th percentile / 99th percentile worst cases is useful to explore the long tail for real-time use-cases.

Comment: Yes, there is 1 chase thread and 15 load thread here, and bandwidth number looks ok. But I didn't the role of chase thread here? and did you mean there is always a cache-miss load while accessing the every 16th byte (that is stride size) from this array of size 512M ?

Comment: @Milan: It's the thread that's actually doing pointer chasing, e.g. `p = *p`, or `p = p->next`, so you're measuring load latency by making each load-address dependent on the previous load's result.  You put "pointer-chasing" in the title so I assume you knew what pointer-chasing was, but I didn't look carefully enough at the question.  Updating my answer.

Comment: latency number is given by ChaseNS field, right ?

Comment: @Milan: Yes, for that amount of competing load.  A more normal load-use latency for a full cache miss all the way to DRAM is more like 40 to 80ns, without contention from load threads.  (https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake.html).  Or apparently some ARM CPUs have much higher latency, like https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Cortex-A76.html reports a Snapdragon 855 having DRAM latency of 140ns (+11 core clock cycles).  For a larger working set, TLB misses can also increase latency.

Comment: Okay, one should see lower number for ChaseNS when only chase thread is used and more the load threads used higher the value for ChaseNS, got your point, Thanks! –

Comment: Looking at the source code, I see a geometric mean calculation for the ChaseNS field.  The geometric mean is almost never the right mean to use for performance-related values.  The arithmetic mean is almost always the correct first choice for latency values.